# Using ssl with Postman and GET

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, postman

I'm working with an API from a private company using java.
I'm trying to make a GET Request with Postman on an URL that they gave to me. I set up an *SSL certificate with the original server URL* and everything is ok. But when i *change the certificate to test server*, i get the following error:

> Error: write EPROTO 101057795:error:14094418:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert unknown ca:c:\projects\electron\vendor\node\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\s3_pkt.c:1494:SSL alert number 48 101057795:error:1409E0E5:SSL routines:ssl3_write_bytes:ssl handshake failure:c:\projects\electron\vendor\node\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\s3_pkt.c:659:

Do you know how to fix it, to make it work on test server too?
Alternatively: does another SSL certificate exists for the test server?

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong certificate. That certificate is not for that server.
You should try to contact that company for the right certificate.